# Datagridview office 2007 theme

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

How can I make the Microsoft datagridview looks like the outlook office 2007 grid.
I want the datagridview to looks like this grid
I tried changing the colors and played with the cell and header design but no result, I do not know what is the name or the code of this light blue color.
[image: I want the datagridview to looks like this grid]

Comment: I guess the only way to archieve that is handling the Drawing-Event yourself. Good luck

Comment: hhh.. I will ignore then...thank you